# AngularDart - Manipulate DOM from Component

Tags: html, angularjs, dart

so I am using the standard template from AngularDart that comes from stagehand web-angular-simple.
Now, if I have something hardcoded in index.html and try to manipulate it from main.dart using querySelector, everything works fine.

But how can I use querySelector to manipulate the AppComponent that was loaded into the index.html file in the template?

So basically my question is: how to manipulate dynamically loaded elements in dart.
(p.s. I just started out in AngularDart...)

thanks in advance

Comment: Dynamically manipulate how exactly? What are you trying to accomplish? The normal way is to use components and directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` to manipulate the DOM instead of direct DOM manipulation using code. If you still want direct DOM manipulation, it depends on what you want to do exactly to be able to tell how it could be done.

Comment: So basically I want to change the dynamic content afterwars. Lets say I use a component, add some dynamic stuff to my website and want to access a specific element later on by for example targeting the id and changing the text. Where would I do that? (use case would be like a one page application where something changes onclick)

Comment: "some dynamic stuff" is not much more concrete than the original question ;-) Please add some code that shows what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, let's say my component template looks like this:

<li *ngFor="let elem of elements">
  <p id="thename">{{elem.name}}</p>
</li>

Now, I decide I want to change every text with the id of 'thename'.
So I would do something like:

querySelector("#thename").text = "Changed Text";

But when I put the second line of code in main.dart, it doesn't find the reference to the id of thename. So my question is at which point is the DOM ready for this line of code if the previous <li> block was loaded from a component?

Comment: You should use template binding for that `{{someField}}` in the template and then update the value of `someField` in the component to get the view updated by Angular. See https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular for more detaila

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject ElementRef and through it access nativeElement - this will be the DOM node of you component.

The question is why do you need? Almost always there is a way to do what you need through interacting with angular templates.

Comment: yep, I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the angular way of doing things. Thanks :)